# Correct way to pass prototype to an object

Tags: javascript

My understanding of prototypes is as follows:

```
let Animal = function() {
    this.bark = "woof";
}

Animal.prototype.barkLoud = function() {
     return this.bark.toUpperCase();    
}

let x = new Animal();

x.barkLoud() = "WOOF";
```

Everything above makes sense to me but then I saw a tutorial what seemingly appears to be 2 different ways to pass prototypes to an object. Are these the same thing?  If so, which approach is better:

```
let obj = {
    age: 45;
    __proto__: Animal
}
```

**vs**

```
let obj = {
   age: 45;
}

obj.prototype = Object.create(Animal.protoype);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, the more underscore (`_`) characters you see around a property name in JS, the more of implementation details it is - and the more discouraged you are from even querying it, let alone attempting to modify.

While `__proto__` is indeed supported by all the existing browsers, its usage to set up a prototype is not recommended. Use Object.create() instead.

BTW, two ways you've showed are not even equivalent. See, `__proto__` refers to the prototype object, but `Animal` is not the one - it's a function. `Animal.prototype` is an object that will be used as a prototype (`__proto__ value) for all the objects created by this function with` new` operator.

So the first object won't be able to resolve `barkLoud` name from the prototype chain:

```
> obj.barkLoud // undefined
```

Comment: thanks @raina77ow .  I just tried to run this code in console and `obj.prototype = Object.create(Animal.protoype);` gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined`

Comment: If you want to connect a prototype to an already existing object, you can use `Object.setPrototypeOf()` instead. But in your case, I'd rather create an object with `Object.create` first, then assign properties to this object.

Answer (score 0):

`__proto__` way is deprecated by the way and I've never seen it implemented anywhere.

Go with `Object.create` as the official and recommended way to create/assign prototype of existing object to the newly created object.